# Get group of relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship, eloquent

I'm using laravel 4.2 and i have a model `Items`, that model items belongs to a model `Category`, the model `Category` has some text and a slug for pretty url in search.

Item Model:

```
class Item extends Eloquent{
 public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category','cat_id');
    }
}
```

Category Model:

```
class Category extends Eloquent{
}
```

If i do `Items::with('category')->get()` it will retrieve this:

```
//items
[
 {
    "id": 26,
    "cat_id": 14,
    "category": {
       "id": 14,
       "slug": 'unique-text',
       "description": 'text',
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "cat_id": 13,
    "category": {
       "id": 13,
       "slug": "unique-text2",
       "description": "text2",
   },
   {
    "id": 25,
    "cat_id": 13,
    "category": {
       "id": 13,
       "slug": "unique-text2",
       "description": "text2",
   },
]
```

**The question**

How can i retrieve the `categories` form the relationship without having to access each `item` and, how can i retrieve only those `categories` that do not repeat.

for example, in the data shown above, 2 items have the same `category id = 13`

i want to show only `Categories: text / text2` as in group by.

**EDITED**

the `Item` may be filtered, so i need the category based on the result of the `Item` query, so if i do `Item::where('price','>','20')-with('category')->get()` i need to group the categories of those items, i do not need all the items.

Comment: you can do `category->get()` or try to make raw query

Answer (score 0):

you can just do `category->get()` or try to write raw query to get distinct categories but category->get will do the work just as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unique categories like this:

```
$categories = Items::with('category')->get()->pluck('category')->unique();
```